# Replicate the same position functionality of Google Calendar events popup panel

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, material-design

## The problem

I'm searching for anything that could tell me more about how to replicate the same functionality of this specific panel, but no luck finding any tutorial or useful code.

#### The functionality is

- The panel popups when clicking events on the calendar.
- The panel somehow calculates width of client screen to know where's the best area of the screen to place the panel.
- At the same time, when clicking on another event, the panel of the current opened event simply transition into the other, without a closing transition on the current panel and a opening transition on the other event panel.

**The final result seems like is the same panel that travels on the screen based on what event you click, and transitions its content into the current active event.**

## What i already did

I'm using the fullcalendar plugin. It provides some useful data to use when [`clickEvent`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) function is triggered, such as click position on screen etc.

I indeed reached a very close behavior, but i still have some problems calculating the best place to show the panel.

[Here is a working pen](https://codepen.io/kaiten/pen/XowLzO?editors=1010).

## Expected results

I expect a better logic to calculate the best place to show the panel without breaking screen width nor height, working on any screen size.

**Here is my current logic**

```
  if ((eventX) > screenX / 2) {
    panel.css('right',eventX + jsEvent.currentTarget.clientWidth)
    panel.css('top',eventY)
  } else {
    panel.css('left',eventX)
    panel.css('top',eventY)
  }
```

Appreciate!

Comment: Are you set on writing this all yourself, or would you be happy using a plugin e.g. https://popper.js.org/tooltip-examples.html

Comment: being able to replicate that exactly functionality, ill be happy using the plugin. but i dont think showing just a popover is my main objective.

Comment: Ok so what is your main objective then?